# Correlation of independent random processes

Tags: autocorrelation, cross-correlation, correlation, random-process, random

Suppose $X(t)$ and $Y(t)$ be two independent random processes. Is $E(X(t_1)Y(t_2))$ necessarily zero?

Comment: No. $E<X \cdot Y>$ is simply $E<X> \cdot E<Y>$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Quoting Wikipedia's article [Independence (probability theory)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)):

> If $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables,
>   then the expectation operator $\operatorname{E}$ has the property
>
> $$\operatorname{E}[X Y] = \operatorname{E}[X]\operatorname{E}[Y].$$

Consider your $X(t_1)$ and $Y(t_2)$ as $X$ and $Y$ in this answer. If both $\operatorname{E}[X] \ne 0$ and $\operatorname{E}[X] \ne 0,$ then the product  $\operatorname{E}[X]\operatorname{E}[Y]$ will be non-zero.